# How do you set up formatting in vim?

Tags: vim, python-3.x

Earlier, when I used open .py files in vim on ubuntu, they would be well formatted, with separate colours for separate segments of the program. Now, when I am using VIM on ubuntu, all the text in the .py file appears black. How can I correct this?

Comment: What does the documentation have to say about that?

Comment: Ok. Got it. Did not know how to search for the correct thing.

Comment: @Renan that's not completely fair. As a new user to Vim it can be a bit overwhelming to find the right part of the help docs.

Comment: Well Yes, I tried for quite some time. Didn't know it was called syntax highlighting.

Comment: @JonathanCairns That's no excuse. If being easy to use is a concern, there are always other more user friendly text editors.

Comment: add two lines to your .vimrc one:`filetype plugin indent on` two:`syntax on` then open a py again. see if it looks different. well, you need a color-monitor to test syntax highlighting. :)

Comment: @Renan vim is easy to use, isn't it?

Comment: @Renan what I said doesn't apply to Vim in particular, or even finding something in a help file. You could always say "you should know that", but for beginners they might just need a nudge in the right direction. A more helpful comment would have been "check the documentation with :help ...`

Comment: @JonathanCairns I totally agree. However, I could not divine that he had gone through the docs prior to posting. The question sounded like he came here for help first. Omitting that you have tried the docs makes `RTFM` a valid answer in most cultures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `man vim`. In a nutshell, find a copy of a vimrc file, one might be under `/usr/share/vim/` subtree. It may be named `vimrc_example.vim`. Copy to your home directory and rename it as `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

*Formating* in Vim means text formatting; e.g. indenting lists and breaking long lines. You're concerned about *syntax highlighting*, which is purely about the visual appearance of code.

First, it needs to be turned on.

```
:syntax on
```

does that.

Second, you probably want Vim to automatically detect the used language (e.g. *Python*) and choose the correct syntax plugin for you.

```
:filetype on
```

does that, though you usually enable more via `:filetype plugin indent on`.

To make these settings persistent, put them into your `~/.vimrc` configuration.